# Make CodeMirror substring Bold without changing mode

Tags: javascript, primefaces, codemirror, primefaces-extensions

I am using codemirror with primefaces extensions in XML Mode. Now, I have to change the font of substring to Bold. For example

```
<User>
    <Name>Micheal</Name>
    <Age>25</Age>
    <Address>**NewYork**</Address>
</User>
```

Here NewYork should be in Bold and mode should be XML. Please help me how to achieve this, I am using codemirror for the first time. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see any PrimeFaces usage in here... Did you try with plain codemirror? Does it work then?

Comment: I used like this <pe:codeMirror id="codeMirror" mode="#{codeMirrorController.mode}"  
    theme="eclipse" value="#{codeMirrorController.content}" lineNumbers="true"/> It is working, I can see XML Highlighting. But my question is how to change  font of one attribute 'NewYork' to Bold ?

Comment: And my question was: does it work/can it be achieved  with plain codemirror

Answer (score 0):

If you know where your substring is, you can call `markText` to add a CSS class to it.

(That was linked to http:/codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#markText , but apparently StackOverflow helpfully removes the link as some kind of heavy-handed anti-spam measure?)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am using markText but it is not working. I am using like this doc.markText({line:3,ch:14},{line:3,ch:20},"font-weight: bold");

Comment: Your last argument isn't the kind of thing that the function expects. Check the docs.